# Is there way for git status to show changes for certain time?

Tags: git, command

I would like to know if I can show changes in a project directory for a certain time period. Lets say show only changes made today?

Is there way to do that from command line with Git?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible to show the date/time of changes with Git if they were not committed. For commits, you can use the following arguments of **`git log`**:

- `--since=<date>` / `--after=<date>` to show commits more recent than a specific date
- `--until=<date>` / `--before=<date>` to show commits older than a specific date

*Examples:*

```sh
git log --after="2021-05-02"
git log --since="2021-06-12" --before="2021-06-22"
git log --after="2021-03-16T18:05:00+02:00"         # ISO 8601
git log --before="2021-03-16T13:12:05Z"             # ISO 8601
git log --since="3 month ago"
git log --since="2 weeks 5 days ago"
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `git status` has a way of doing that, but you can use `git log` instead:

```
git log --since="9am"
```